# Facebook Get User Profile Picture w/ID

Tags: c#, ios, facebook, rest, xamarin

I am attempting to get a user profile picture with Restsharp and C# but I am returning this error for every user on my timeline: `{"error":{"message":"(#210) Subject must be a page.","type":"OAuthException","code":210}}` Here is how I am attempting to GET the picture:

```
IEnumerable<Account> accounts = AccountStore.Create ().FindAccountsForService ("Facebook");
var enumerable = accounts as IList<Account> ?? accounts.ToList ();
Account facebook = enumerable.First ();
var facebookAccessToken = facebook.Properties ["access_token"].ToString ();
var request = new RestRequest (id + "/picture", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter ("access_token", facebookAccessToken);


var client = new RestClient ("https://graph.facebook.com/");
IRestResponse resp = client.Execute (request);
return resp.Content.ToString ();
```

How would i fix this?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @valdetero How would i fix this?